# How do I specify a relation in SQLAlchemy where one condition requires a column to be null?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship

Not sure what the correct title for this question should be. I have the following schema:

- Matters have a one-many relationship to WorkItems.
- WorkItems have a one-one (or one-zero) relationship to LineItems.

I am trying to create the following relation between Matters and WorkItems

```
Matter.unbilled_work_items = orm.relation(WorkItem,
  primaryjoin = (Matter.id == WorkItem.matter_id) and (WorkItem.line_item_id == None),
  foreign_keys = [WorkItem.matter_id, WorkItem.line_item_id],
  viewonly=True
)
```

This throws:

```
AttributeError: '_Null' object has no attribute 'table'
```

That seems to be saying that the second clause in the primaryjoin returns an object of type _Null, but it seems to be expecting something with a "table" attribute.

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward to me, am I missing something obvious?

**Update**

The answer was to change the `primaryjoin` line to:

```
primaryjoin = "and_(Matter.id == WorkItem.matter_id, WorkItem.line_item_id == None)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `and_` as `and` is not overloaded:

```
and_((Matter.id == WorkItem.matter_id), (WorkItem.line_item_id == None))
```

Comment: The `&` operator is overloaded, so you could also write (...) & (...)

Comment: The problem with & is that it binds stronger than ==.
So `x == 'a' & y == 'b'` would turn into `(x == ('a' & y)) == 'b'`

Comment: Yes, that is why you need the parenthesis: `(x=='a') & (y=='b')`

Comment: I came back to try this again recently, it's the right answer. The issue was that, with the declarative style, the entire expression needs to be quoted, including `and_()`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the _Null issue, this requires a left outer join to do correctly. I've decided that unbilled_work_items should be a property that executes a query and returns the result.

```
# like this

@property
def unbilled_work_items(self):
  return Session.object_session(self).query.filter(...).all()
```